# Modified SDA1 by mistake, Windows does not open on a dual boot

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I use dualboot with Windows and Linux, my partitions look like below:

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 409602047 409395200 195.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       409602048 693557205 283955158 135.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       693557246 976771071 283213826   135G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       968550400 976771071   8220672   3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       693557248 968550399 274993152 131.1G 83 Linux
```

When I was creating a Linux Mint installation USB, with following command

```
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct  bs=1048576
```

By mistake I wrote sda1, instead of sdb. Thus now **I cannot start Windows.** 
I get this error:

```
error:no such device: 3AE081F1E08
Setting partition type to 0x7
```

But Program Files, Windows files are on Sda2, which is untouched.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You used the Data Destroyer command on the partition.  Everything on that partition is gone so likely the best course of action is to just reinstall.  Windows first as it will clobber the bootloader anyway and then Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Boot a Windows installation medium, get into its command prompt, format the first partition and use this:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824874.aspx

Then boot into Linux and update the grub menu